# IOS Swift TI SensorTag2 data conversion

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I write an app for iOS using the TI SensorTag2. Right now i'm stuck with the conversion of data i read over bluetooth to Float for the app.

Following Code is from the released source code of TI for an Objective C App.

```
-(NSString *) calcValue:(NSData *) value {

char vals[value.length];
[value getBytes:vals length:value.length];

Point3D gyroPoint;

gyroPoint.x = ((float)((int16_t)((vals[0] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[1] << 8) & 0xff00)))/ (float) 32768) * 255 * 1;
gyroPoint.y = ((float)((int16_t)((vals[2] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[3] << 8) & 0xff00)))/ (float) 32768) * 255 * 1;
gyroPoint.z = ((float)((int16_t)((vals[4] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[5] << 8) & 0xff00)))/ (float) 32768) * 255 * 1;

self.gyro = gyroPoint;

Point3D accPoint;

accPoint.x = (((float)((int16_t)((vals[6] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[7] << 8) & 0xff00)))/ (float) 32768) * 8) * 1;
accPoint.y = (((float)((int16_t)((vals[8] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[9] << 8) & 0xff00))) / (float) 32768) * 8) * 1;
accPoint.z = (((float)((int16_t)((vals[10] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[11] << 8) & 0xff00)))/ (float) 32768) * 8) * 1;

self.acc = accPoint;

Point3D magPoint;
magPoint.x = (((float)((int16_t)((vals[12] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[13] << 8) & 0xff00))) / (float) 32768) * 4912);
magPoint.y = (((float)((int16_t)((vals[14] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[15] << 8) & 0xff00))) / (float) 32768) * 4912);
magPoint.z = (((float)((int16_t)((vals[16] & 0xff) | (((int16_t)vals[17] << 8) & 0xff00))) / (float) 32768) * 4912);


self.mag = magPoint;


return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ACC : X: %+6.1f, Y: %+6.1f, Z: %+6.1f\nMAG : X: %+6.1f, Y: %+6.1f, Z: %+6.1f\nGYR : X: %+6.1f, Y: %+6.1f, Z: %+6.1f",self.acc.x,self.acc.y,self.acc.z,self.mag.x,self.mag.y,self.mag.z,self.gyro.x,self.gyro.y,self.gyro.z];
}
```

When i try to convert this code to Swift, i get an error "Integer literal '65280' overflows when stored into Int16

```
let xF: Float = ((Float((Int16(bytes[6]) & 0xff) | ((Int16(bytes[7]) << 8) & 0xff00)) / Float(32768)) * 8) * 1
```

As i understand that, it combines the 2 Int8 variables into a single Int16 and it should work, i just don't find where i made the error. The part with "& 0xff00" is marked and when i understand it right this is here so only the first 8 bits contain 1's , the rest is 0's

I had it working with code from the android app for SensorTag2, but that code crashes the app from time to time, when i do also read data from gyroscope, so i wanted to use that iOS Code

```
let x = (Int16(bytes[7]) << 8) + Int16(bytes[6])
let xF = Float(x) / (32768.0 / 8.0)
```

Maybe somebody here can point me in the right direction to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

One bad thing in this line:

```
let xF: Float = ((Float((Int16(bytes[6]) & 0xff) | ((Int16(bytes[7]) << 8) & 0xff00)) / Float(32768)) * 8) * 1
```

is this: `((Int16(bytes[7]) << 8) & 0xff00)`.

You know `Int16` can represent numbers -32768...32767, and the value of 0xff00 is 65280. As the error message is saying, it is too large for `Int16`.

(Remember Swift does no implicit conversions for numeric types.)

With making `bytes` as unsigned:

```
let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
```

You have no need to use `&`.

But you need to pass a signed value to `Float.init`, so your code needs to be something like this:

```
let xF: Float = ((Float(Int16(bitPattern: UInt16(bytes[6]) | (UInt16(bytes[7]) << 8))) / Float(32768)) * 8) * 1
```

(Or else, negative values in `bytes` make your app crash.)

Comment: I had the code for that line from the Objective C version of the app

Comment: I still don't understand what would be wrong with that, because it's no addition, it should be a bitwise operation.
When i understand it right they first convert the 8bit variable to 16bit

0xab => 0x00ab

then shift it left by 8

0xab00

and the last operation is to only keep what is in the first 8 bits, because it could maybe happen that shifting leads to 0xabcd, so a (bits & 0xff00) should just make it safe

0xab00

Comment: In Swift, treating integers are much different than in C. `&` operator is defined for (`Int16`, `Int16`), or for other types with the same size and signedness. In `((Int16(bytes[7]) << 8) & 0xff00)`, the left hand side `(Int16(bytes[7]) << 8)` is of type `Int16`, so you need to put an `Int16` value on the right hand side.  But Swift can never treat `0xff00` as an `Int16` value, because it exceeds the limit of `Int16`. You may be looking `0xff00` as just a bit-pattern, but so does not Swift. In Swift, it is representing an integer value `65280` and it cannot be contained in `Int16`.

Comment: thanks that helped understanding the flaw in that, so it's not always just adjusting code to swift syntax

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use the UInt solution, because i get the data as raw bytes that are encoded as signed int with 16bit.
In ObjectiveC they are read into a char-array, that i converted to Int8

But i found another solution and now i just read the bytes into a Int16 array, that way two following bytes will be treated as a single Int16, like the ObjectiveC code made them already.

```
var bytes: [Int16] = [Int16](count: data.length, repeatedValue: 0)
let dataLength = data.length
data.getBytes(&bytes, length: dataLength * sizeof(Int16))
```

That way i don't need the bitshifting and bit operations.

now i have an array of 9 Int16 values, instead of 16 Int8, that i had to convert to Int16.
Also a test with the TI SensorTag App resulted in the same numbers

Comment: To make your solution to work, the byte alignment of the target CPU needs to be "little endian". And luckily all targets of iOS/Swift (iOS - recent ARMs, Simulator - x86/x64) are little endian. So, your solution is safe as for now. But some people does not prefer such "byte-order dependent" codes, especially when treating communication results. Anyway it's your choice.

Comment: I keep that in mind, the app should later also be created for Android, but TI did release a full Android Sourcecode of their sensorTag App, so i can get correct code from there.